# Counterexample to second derivative test when f''(x) is not continuously differentiable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

When looking over true/false questions on previous midterms, one of my conscientious students said:

"If f is defined on an open interval containing c, f'(c)=0, and f''(c)>0, then c is a local min of f"

was false because one of the hypotheses for the second derivative test (at least in Stewart) is that the second derivative is continuous in a neighborhood of c.

Can anyone think of a counterexample for this statement (in one real variable)? It's apparently been too long since I've taken an analysis class to come up with something clever.

Comment: I don't think continuity is actually required.  The first derivative has to exist in a neighborhood for the second derivative to exist.  The assumption that $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f'(c+h)-f'(c)}{h} > 0$ combined with $f'(c) = 0$ implies that $f'(c+h) > 0$ for $h>0$ and $h$ small enough and $< 0$ for $h < 0$ and $h$ small enough.  From here it's a consequence of the mean value theorem.

Comment: Ah thanks. I didn't consider that Stewart would just add an unnecessary hypothesis to the statement of a theorem when it doesn't even bother to prove it.

I won't feel too bad about not finding a counterexample then!

Comment: I suppose the hypothesis is an artifact of thinking of the multivariable case, where one wants equality of mixed partials.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out in the comments, the fact that $f'(c)=0$ is enough; the continuity of the second derivative is not required for a single variable case.