# If $f$ is continuous, $f'(c)=0$ and $f''(c)<0$, then $f(x)<f(c)$ for all $x$ in an interval around $c$?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is continuous, $f'(c)=0$ and $f''(c)<0$, does that imply that there exists some interval around $c$ such that $f(x)<f(c)$ for all $x$ in the interval?

I've discussed this on reddit and I think the answer is no.   It would be true if $f''$ was continuous at $c$.  However I cannot seem to find an explicit function as a counterexample.  Can anyone think of one?

EDIT:  In fact the implication is true without $f''$ continuity at $c$ answered below.

Also can anyone clarify that concavity at $c$ does not make sense since concavity/concexity only makes sense over an interval?  I believe I got a wrong impression from school or a book, or something.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547312/counterexample-to-second-derivative-test-when-fx-is-not-continuously-differe?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We assume that $f$ is two-times differentiable in $(a,b)$ with $c\in (a,b)$ (no need of the continuity of $f''$). By the definition of second-derivative,
$$0>f''(c)=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f'(x)-f'(c)}{x-c}=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f'(x)}{x-c}$$
which implies that, by the definition of limit, there is $\delta>0$ such that ,
$$\forall x\in(c-\delta,c)\cup(c,c+\delta),\quad\frac{f'(x)}{x-c}<0$$
that is $f'(t)>0$ in $(c-\delta,c)$ and $f'(t)<0$ in $(c,c+\delta)$.
Now note that by the Mean Value Theorem, if $x\in(c-\delta)\cup(c,c+\delta)$ then for some $t$ between $x$ and $c$
$$f(x)-f(c)=f'(t)(x-c)<0$$
that is $c$ is a **strict local maximum point** in $(a,b)$.

Comment: Is there a term for a maximum value that is in fact strictly greater in an interval?

Comment: Yes, $f(c)$ is strict maximum value.

Comment: Hmm  In spivak's Calculus he only mentions $c$ to be a min/max point (which is kinda disappointing since its suppose to be rigorous book).  Is there also a term for the maximum point associated with the strictly maximum value?

Comment: Strict local maximum point (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima#Definition)